# Print PDF file with printdialog vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, printing, printdialog

I'm trying to print a external pdf file with printdialog options but the file is printed with predeterminated printer config

```
Dim result As DialogResult = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog()
        If (result = DialogResult.OK) Then
            Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo
            psi.UseShellExecute = True
            psi.Verb = "print"
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            psi.Arguments = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName.ToString()
            psi.FileName = "file.pdf"
            Process.Start(psi)
        End If
```

Comment: What's the point of calling `ToString` on a property that is type `String`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use the "PrintTo" verb rather than the "Print" verb. You would also need to wrap the printer name in quotes if it might have spaces in it. I would suggest making your code a bit more succinct:

```vb
Process.Start(New ProcessStartInfo("file.pdf",
                                   $"""{PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName}""") With {.Verb = "printto",
                                                                                            .UseShellExecute = True,
                                                                                            .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden})
```